Dynamic routing with Stack and Tab Navigation in expo-router
I new to RN and I am trying to use expo router in my app. But I experience an issue with the structure of the files. Right now the structure is like this:
File structure
I use the (app) for authentication. But bsically the index.tsx is my Home Page, which contains event cards like this:
Home page
I need to add a dynamic route so that when a user presses a card it is redirected to the details of this event. And it should be able to navigate back and have the tab below. But I am having issues how to structure the files.
This is my
(app)/_layout.tsx

import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {Redirect, Tabs} from 'expo-router';
import {useAuth} from "@/app/context/context";
import React from "react";
import { TabBarIcon } from '@/components/navigation/TabBarIcon';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';


export default function AppLayout() {
  const { user, isLoading } = useAuth();
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  // You can keep the splash screen open, or render a loading screen like we do here.
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }

  // Only require authentication within the (app) group's layout as users
  // need to be able to access the (auth) group and sign in again.
  if (!user) {
    // On web, static rendering will stop here as the user is not authenticated
    // in the headless Node process that the pages are rendered in.
    return <Redirect href="/sign-in" />;
  }

  // This layout can be deferred because it's not the root layout.
  return (
      <Tabs
          screenOptions={{
            tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
          }}>
        <Tabs.Screen
            name="index"
            options={{
              title: 'Home',
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
                  <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'} color={color} />
              ),
            }}
        />
          <Tabs.Screen
              name="create-event"
              options={{
                  title: 'Create',
                  tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
                      <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'add' : 'add-outline'} color={color} />
                  ),
              }}
          />
        <Tabs.Screen
            name="profile"
            options={{
              title: 'Profile',
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
                  <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'code-slash' : 'code-slash-outline'} color={color} />
              ),
            }}
        />
      </Tabs>
  );
}

This is my index.tsx, which uses EventCard to navigate:
import React, {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {FIRESTORE_DB} from "@/firebaseConfig";
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import EventCard from "../../components/EventCard";

// Event type definition
interface Event {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    date: string;
    time: string;
    location: string;
    availablePlaces: number;
    userId: string;
}

// Main component to render the list of events
const Events = () => {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState<Event[]>([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

    // Fetch events from Firestore
    const fetchEvents = async () => {
        try {
            const eventsCollection = collection(FIRESTORE_DB, 'events');
            const eventSnapshot = await getDocs(eventsCollection);
            const eventList: Event[] = eventSnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
            })) as Event[];
            setEvents(eventList);
            console.log("Index: ", eventList);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching events: ", error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            fetchEvents();
        }, [])
    );


    if (loading) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
                <Text>Loading Events...</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={events}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <EventCard event={item} />}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default Events;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 16,
        backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    },
    loadingContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    card: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 12,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 4 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 6,
        elevation: 5,
        marginBottom: 16,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 150,
    },
    cardContent: {
        padding: 12,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#333',
        marginBottom: 8,
    },
    time: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#38A169', // Greenish text for time
        marginBottom: 4,
    },
    location: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#888', // Light gray for location
    },
});


And this is the EventCard component:
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router';

// Event type definition
interface Event {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    date: string;
    time: string;
    location: string;
    availablePlaces: number;
    userId: string;
}

// Card component to display event details
const EventCard: React.FC<{ event: Event }> = ({ event }) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    // Combine the date and time into a single Date object
    const eventDateTime = new Date(`${event.date}T${event.time}`);

    // Format the time and day
    const formattedTime = eventDateTime.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
    const formattedDay = eventDateTime.toLocaleDateString([], { weekday: 'long' });

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => router.push(`/event/${event.id}`)}>
            <View style={styles.card}>
                <Image
                    source={{
                        uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612534847738-b3af9bc31f0c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80',
                    }} // Replace with dynamic event image URL
                    style={styles.image}
                />
                <View style={styles.cardContent}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{event.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.time}>
                        {formattedTime} / {formattedDay}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.location}>{event.location}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

export default EventCard;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 12,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 4 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 6,
        elevation: 5,
        marginBottom: 16,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 150,
    },
    cardContent: {
        padding: 12,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#333',
        marginBottom: 8,
    },
    time: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#38A169', // Greenish text for time
        marginBottom: 4,
    },
    location: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#888', // Light gray for location
    },
});


I want to be able to have both Stack and Tab navigation in the home page.
